# Seeking Collection/Catalogue software for _music_ similar to functionality to _YACReader_

Tags: software-recommendation, music

Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

I have music in the following structure on disk:

```
--music
  -- artist_1
       -- music_1
       -- music_2
           -- cover.jpg/png
           -- 1.mp3
           -- 2.mp3
           -- N.mp3
  -- artist_2
       -- music_1
       -- music_2
       -- music_3
  -- artist_3
       -- music_1
```

I would like to know if there's an **opensource** specific software out there that lets me **read the structure and display my cover for each melody in a grid, just like YACReader**.

**I need to be able to tag them and search them as well.**

Example:

[image]

It would be a bonus if, just like YACReader, it can stream the content to an Android App via it's server aware feature.

Thank you.